# Apache2 how to working www.example.com

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I need help. I am sorry wrong write. My LAMP server I created virtual host working http://example.com , but it is **NOT WORKING**.

```
$ping www.example.com 
ping: unknown host www.example.com
```

My configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example/1/public_html"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias   www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    UseCanonicalName on

    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride all
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/example/1/public_html">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you define exactly what "not working" means? How are you testing? What errors are you getting? What, if any, commands did you run after trying to configure `www.example.com`?

Comment: example.com my web site working a www.example.com not working my s

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: ping www.example.com
ping: unknown host www.example.com

Comment: Ping has nothing to do with your Apache configuration. This looks more like a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ping www.example.com ping: unknown host www.example.com –  DasturchiUZ

You need to create a DNS A record for `www.example.com` so it resolves to your server's IP address.

Do that with the company you registered the domain `example.com`.

Comment: example.com. IN A IP_ADRESS
www.example.com IN A IP_ADRESS

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to publish the exact config above, `example.com` is only a placeholder used for configuration templates. 
http://example.com/

> Example Domain
>
> This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in
>   documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior
>   coordination or asking for permission.

To test virtual hosts without a valid DNS you could try editing your hosts file - C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
10.x.x.x    www.example.com
```

where 10.x.x.x is the ip address of the server running Apache.

Comment: This method is only for my computer

Comment: I am using others computers